# jQuery open a hidden div upward over a div

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, menu

I have a structure like this.

```
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder2_div_Menu" class="bottom-link">
    <ul class='forlasttooltip'>
        <li>
            <div class='orange-button divm'>
                3G/GPRS</div>
            <div class='tooltip'>
                <div class='tooltipinner'>
                    <ul>
                        <li class='li' rel='#yesno'><a href='my.aspx' rel='#overlay'>How to configure GPRS?</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='li' rel='#yesno'><a href='test.aspx' rel='#overlay'>How to Browse Internet?</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='li' rel='#yesno'><a href='test1.aspx' rel='#overlay'>How to select 3G Network?</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class='orange-button divm'>
                Email</div>
            <div class='tooltip'>
                <div class='tooltipinner'>
                    <ul>
                        <li class='li' rel='#yesno'><a href='' rel='#overlay'>How To Configure Email?</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='li' rel='#yesno'><a href='' rel='#overlay'>Exchange Mail Configuration</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class='orange-button divm'>
                MMS</div>
            <div class='tooltip'>
                <div class='tooltipinner'>
                    <ul>
                        <li class='li' rel='#yesno'><a href='' rel='#overlay'>How to Send MMS?</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class='orange-button-d divm'>
                Speed<br />
                Issue</div>
            <div class='tooltip'>
                <div class='tooltipinner'>
                    <ul>
                        <li class='li' rel='#yesno'><a href='tet.aspx'
                            rel='#overlay'>How to clear cache and cookies?</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to open the `div` with class `tooltip` when user mouse over the `div` with class `divm`.
It's like menu opening above the div.
Earlier I was using `tooltip` of `flowplayer` which is not available now.
As below

[image]

Thanks.

### Edit

I have created a fidle http://jsfiddle.net/c2pdG/28/

Comment: as I written I was using a third party jQuery which was giving me this facility. but it is not working properly. it has a method for tooltip as $(".divm").tooltip().

Comment: Please specify the jquery plugin in the question.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I know how to hide unhide div I have tried .mosueover function but not able to open it upward it is opening downward. Do I wll have to visibility as well as position of each li of .ttoltipinner?

Comment: @krshekhar Can you create an example on jsfiddle.net that shows it opening downward?

Comment: @ExplosionPills sorry for my late response I have created a jsfiddle the url is http://jsfiddle.net/c2pdG/22/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/c2pdG/23/

This is more of a CSS question.  I updated the CSS so that it will work as you like, but you may need to have more tweaks -- your original code was not working perfectly either.

Essentially, the menu items that contain the submenu should have `position: relative` and `overflow: visible`.  Then, the submenu (tooltip) needs `position: absolute` and `bottom: 100%`, which will position it with its bottom affixed tot he top of its relative parent (i.e. `.bottom-link`).

Even though the animation is using `.slideDown`, it will still appear to animate upwards.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are many things which I came to know from this post. But what you told I am amazed by that. Shall you provide me some link from where I can learn these trics. Though I had created  new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c2pdG/28/ for the same.

Comment: @krshekhar unfortunately there's no link to my brain .. I learned a lot of this stuff myself through experience and reading *tons* of different links online.  Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I had also some problem with the sub menu in IE. If there was some link behind (on the page) then the `tooltip` was closing autometically.  What I did, I put an image in the background of submenu `li` and it started working fine. I was not able to know the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this

```
$(".divm").mouseover(function(){

 var position = $(this).offset(); // calculate the position of click

 var winH = $(window).height();   

 var left = position.left;        // calculation bottom left position of tooltip to be displayed
 var bottom  = winH-position.top
$(".tooltip").attr("style","left:"+left+"px;bottom:"+bottom +"px;").show();

});
```

Comment: @krshekhar - so now it is opening upward....do u want any other modifications in it ??

Comment: Yes it is working but what about hiding the same. There is some problem in IE if the number of li increases the behavior is very bad.

Comment: thanks a lot but the position relative is the beeter option of @ExplosionPills is good.

Answer (score -1):

If you can control the source code I would just switch the positions of the divs

```
<li>
        <div class='tooltip'>
            <div class='tooltipinner'>
                <ul>
                    <li class='li' rel='#yesno'><a href='my.aspx' rel='#overlay'>How to configure GPRS?</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class='li' rel='#yesno'><a href='test.aspx' rel='#overlay'>How to Browse Internet?</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class='li' rel='#yesno'><a href='test1.aspx' rel='#overlay'>How to select 3G Network?</a></li></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='orange-button divm'>
            3G/GPRS</div>
    </li>
```

This will open the tooltip div above the divm div.

If not, try using the prependTo() jQuery Method

```
$('.tooltip').prependTo($('.tooltip').parent());
```

This will "move" the element to the top element in within it's parent which is the li tag.

So your function may look like this:

```
$(".divm").mouseover(function(){
    $('.tooltip').prependTo($('.tooltip').parent()).show();
}
```

Comment: Use sibling selector: `$(this).next('.tooltip').toggle()` and use css to position relative to the container (li).

Comment: what about opening it upwards